# android update row in table

Tags: android, mysql, phpmyadmin

***I have a wamp server with an mysql database:***
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5PHs.png)

I have a Login and Registration System. And i want to allow my users to change their username whenever they want.

In the picture above you will see one user. My Goal is to change the name of this user.

***I have my Database class:***

```
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

// Login table name
private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

// Login Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE," + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

    Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Storing user details in database
 * */
public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
    values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

    // Inserting Row

    long id = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id);
}

/**
 * Getting user data from database
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + user.toString());

    return user;
}

/**
 * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
 * */
public void deleteUsers() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Delete All Rows
    db.delete(TABLE_USER, null, null);
    db.close();


    Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all user info from sqlite");
}

}
```

**Beside all those classes i added this class for the update:**

```
public void updateUsername(String uid, String name) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //Values i want to upgrade  
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name

    String whereQuery = "unique_id= " + uid;

    // Update Row
    db.update(TABLE_USER, values, whereQuery, null);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    Log.d(TAG, "Username updated into sqlite: ");
}
```

**And in the ProfileChangeFragment. I use it:**

```
public class ProfileChangeFragment extends Fragment {
Button btn;
EditText editText;
private SQLiteHandler db;


public static final ProfileChangeFragment newInstance()
{
    ProfileChangeFragment mf = new ProfileChangeFragment();
    Bundle bd = new Bundle(1);
    mf.setArguments(bd);
    return mf;
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profilechange, container, false);

    btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        // Get text which i want to set in table
        String name = editText.getText().toString().trim();

        // Get uid with getUserDetails method
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
        String uid = user.get("uid");

        // Now update       
        db.updateUsername(uid,name);

        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

**And when i click the button the application crashes. Maybe its because the OnClick Method cant handle all that database stuff?**

Comment: Where is that mysql database? Also you are using LIMIT 0 in first sql statement. It won't return anything.

Comment: Wait i will post it

Comment: can you post the logcat error ? And add this line after `String uid = user.get("uid");`. `Log.d("ID",uid)`. See what value is printed.

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT 0 so that return no result. It should be LIMIT 1

Comment: Okey i will check it now

Comment: Doenst change username either

Comment: I don't understand your algorithm but if table have not a colum you can't update that colum.

Comment: Do you want check value in colum diferent with your input value, you will update it ?

Comment: Yes. I want to update the previous username. And if another user has the username it should not change

Comment: oh, i think you need consider existsColumnInTable function